# OrderBy Signature Error in Pro LINQ book?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, errata

According to [Pro LINQ: Language Integrated Query in C# 2008](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590597897), Prototype of *OrderBy* operator is

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T, K>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, K> keySelector)
where
    K : IComparable<K>
```

But the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) does not have a generics contraint on *TKey* that it should be of type `IComparable<TKey>`

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

I am basically sorting Inventory by *Unit* and then by *Size*.

```
    var sortedInventories = inventories
                            .OrderBy(inventory => inventory.Unit)
                            .OrderBy(inventory => inventory.Size);
```

From the above code snippet, lambda expressions simply return inventory properties to sort by.  It does not look like an expression that returns `IComparer<T>`

But according to logic, it looks like the lambda expression should be of type `IComparer<T>`.

**Which one is the correct declaration of `OrderBy`?**
(Apress.com [Errata page](http://www.apress.com/book/errata/648) has no information on it)

Here is a sample application I created to test `OrderBy`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inventories = new[] {
            new Inventory { Unit = 1, Size = 2 },
            new Inventory { Unit = 2, Size = 4 },
            new Inventory { Unit = 3, Size = 6 },
        };
        var sortedInventories = inventories
                                .OrderBy(inventory => inventory.Unit)
                                .OrderBy(inventory => inventory.Size);

        foreach (var inventory in sortedInventories)
            Console.WriteLine("Unit: {0}; Size = {1}", inventory.Unit, inventory.Size);
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your second "OrderBy" to "ThenBy". You're currently *resorting* everything, so it's effectively by Size and then Unit, but inefficiently. I'm not sure where you think `IComparer<T>` should come in, unless you specify it as another argument. Basically it uses `Comparer<T>.Default` unless you specify a separate comparer.

Anyway, your query should be:

```
var sortedInventories = inventories
                          .OrderBy(inventory => inventory.Unit)
                          .ThenBy(inventory => inventory.Size);
```

(With your test data you can't tell the difference, because in each case `Size = Unit * 2`. Try it with one item which has a small Unit and a large Size though.)

Yes, it looks like the book got the signature slightly wrong - possibly due to it changing shortly before release. If you were basically worried about getting the wrong results though, the above is the explanation.

Comment: Next section in the book deals with "ThenBy"...  By the way, does this mean prototype of "OrderBy" (mentioned in the question) is not correct and I would have assume that MSDN document is the most current signature?

Comment: Yes, generally go with MSDN - they usually get the signatures right at least.

Comment: Call we crazy, but I just use intellisense/object-browser/show-definition - nothing to get wrong then. Although of course MSDN is generated from code anyway (+Sandcastle?)

Comment: @Jon: Ouch, when I changed test data around, I was able to see the use of "ThenBy"